# Find $\lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{k^k}{(k+1)^{k+1}}$

Tags: limits

I have spent the better part of this day trying to solve $$\lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{k^k}{(k+1)^{k+1}}$$ When I write this in Wolfram, it says the limit $= 0$, but I don't understand how it got to that conclusion.

Comment: Hint:  write your expression as $\left(\frac k{1+k}\right)^k\times \frac 1{1+k}$ and remark that the first term goes to $\frac 1e$.

Comment: You need to know that $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{1}{n})^n$ is well-known to be $e$.

Comment: This isn't rigorous, but it might help from an intuitive perspective. When taking the limit of $(k + 1)^{k + 1}$, the dominant term is always going to be the first term, so we can approximate it as $k^{k + 1}$. $k^k / k^{k + 1} = 1/k$; taking the limit as $k$ goes to $\infty$, we get $0$.

Comment: @almagest Actually you only need to know that $(1+\frac1n)^n$ is bounded. You don't need to know its limit exists.

Comment: @DavidK Good point! But you are unlikely to know one without the other!

Comment: @almagest Pedagogically, most students who know enough to show that $(1+\frac1n)^n$ is bounded _do_ know its limit, because that limit is very likely among the first really useful limits one learns. But it's a lot easier to prove the bounds than to prove the limit, and if you had to justify the answer on something closer to first principles (rather than "my teacher told me this limit"), the approach of merely proving boundedness is a good one, I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{k^k}{(k+1)^{k+1}}=\lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{k^k}{(k+1)^{k}}\cdot\frac{1}{k+1}=\lim_{k \to \infty} \left(\frac{1}{1+\frac1k}\right)^k\cdot\frac{1}{k+1}$$

$$\lim_{k \to \infty}\left(\frac{1}{1+\frac1k}\right)^k=e^{\lim_{k \to \infty}\left(\frac{1}{1+\frac1k}-1\right)\cdot k}=e^{\lim_{k \to \infty}\left(\frac{-1}{1+\frac1k}\right)}=e^{\lim_{k \to \infty}\left(\frac{-k}{1+k}\right)}=\frac1e$$

Thus,
$$\lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{k^k}{(k+1)^{k+1}}=\lim_{k \to \infty} \left(\frac{1}{1+\frac1k}\right)^k\cdot\lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{1}{k+1}=\frac1e\cdot0=0$$

Answer (score 2):

For all $k > 1$,
$$ 0 < \frac{k}{k+1} < 1 $$
and 
$$ 0 < \left(\frac{k}{k+1}\right)^k < 1. $$
But
$$ \frac{k^k}{(k+1)^{k+1}} = \frac{1}{k+1} \left(\frac{k}{k+1}\right)^k. $$

Therefore
$$ 0 < \frac{k^k}{(k+1)^{k+1}} < \frac{1}{k+1} $$
for all $k>1$, and since $\lim_{k\to\infty} \frac{1}{k+1} = 0$,
by the squeeze theorem
$$ \lim_{k\to\infty} \frac{k^k}{(k+1)^{k+1}} = 0 $$

Answer (score 0):

Hint for real numbers $(k+1)^{k+1}\geq k^k$ thus as the k becomes larger the denominator becomes so large that the whole fraction tends to $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that
$$\lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{k^k}{(k+1)^k} = \lim_{k \to \infty} \left( 1-\frac{1}{k+1} \right)^k = \lim_{k \to \infty} \left( \left( 1-\frac{1}{k+1} \right)^{k+1} \right)^{\frac{k}{k+1}} =\left( \frac{1}{e} \right)^1 = \frac{1}{e}$$
Now, your limit is
$$\lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{k^k}{(k+1)^k} \cdot \frac{1}{k+1} = \lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{k^k}{(k+1)^k} \cdot \lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{1}{k+1} = \frac{1}{e} \cdot 0 = 0$$

Answer (score 0):

First, prove that :

$$ \lim \limits_{k \to +\infty} \Big( \frac{k}{k+1} \Big)^{k} = \frac{1}{e}. $$

Then, it follows that :

$$ \lim \limits_{k \to +\infty} \frac{k^{k}}{(k+1)^{k+1}} = 0 $$

because :

$$ \frac{k^{k}}{(k+1)^{k+1}} = \frac{1}{k+1} \Big( \frac{k}{k+1} \Big)^{k}. $$

Answer (score 0):

It's clear that $k^k$ is less than $(k+1)^k$. So you can make an upper bound of $\frac{1}{k+1}$ which clearly converges to zero. Hope this helps..